# debug:deprecations Symfony 6.3, find deprecations

Tags: php, symfony

Does The command "php bin/console debug:deprecations" exists?

This command is used for identifying deprecations in applications?

If does not exists, what is the command to help me to analyzes my codebase and returns a list of deprecated ?

Comment: `bin/console | grep debug` show you all debug commands or have a look at this [article](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5-upgrade/last-deprecations).

Comment: thank you! You are right, I wrote the command wrong, I was try to use php bin/console debug:container --deprecations,  but I will try to see bin/console | grep debug

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no command or library that could do that. There were some libraries like SensioLabs DeprecationDetector, but it's not up-to-date, and it's abandoned.

There is no a shortcut to going through the Upgrade.md of Symfony and doing the job by hand.

The logs and the profiler are a good way to see deprecations. You will be seeing only the deprecations of the code being executed, though.

I heard of this library but haven't tried it : https://github.com/rectorphp/rector they say that they support Symfony in their doc.

Good luck.